# How to empty cart or clear session "externally"

Tags: magento-1, cart, session

I have a unique workflow for redeeming vouchers on our site through Magento. I have a form that users use for inputting a series of vouchers to get products. It isn't "in" Magento as a CMS page or anything of that nature. The code I am using to achieve access to Magento's resources/models is as followed:

```
<?php

require_once('../app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

// Now you can run ANY Magento code you want

/**
* Get the resource model
*/
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
```

I have *several* codes that can be used to clear session or cart contents but for whatever reason, I can't get them to work by just calling on Mage.php. Here are my codes:

Version 1:

```
// Empty shopping cart
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate();
```

Version 2:

```
// Clear session data
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->clear();
```

Version 3:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quote->delete();
```

None of these will work with the method I listed above. I am placing it after the "$resource..." line. Is there a better way to do this?

The Goal: Everytime a user visits this "voucher form", which is the landing page - I want their shopping cart to be emptied. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This one should work as it removes all items from the current quote:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate();
```

But you need to save it afterwards:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->save();
```

By the way, you can remove the following line:

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
```

since you don't use the variable and instantiating this singleton doesn't do anything in particular.

Comment: the `->save()` is the function I needed even in M2.

Comment: This removes all items from the cart but leaves the number of items in cart intact. That means there are no items in cart but it shows the number yet. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get result what you want through this code.

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate();
```

You need to use `->save()` to achieve what you want.

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate()->save();
```

**Hope this will help you.**