# magento 1.9 checkout/onepage back cart empty

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, onepage-checkout

I need to cart empty when user back from `checkout/onepage`.

If it is possible please help me in this.

> Or this is my plan

I have creating a `checkout/onepage` like this

[image]

Here i want to prevent back url in browser & when user click **logo here** link `cart` will `empty`

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/79776/20064

Comment: @Piyush: I need hyperlink for empty cart

Comment: create a controller action and put empty cart code there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to `<a>` tags `href`

```
<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('your_module/your_controller/emptyCart');?>
```

Then in your controller add

```
 public function emptyCartAction()
 {
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->save();
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    return;
 }
```

Comment: Do he need empty cart method or he need to empty cart after user back from checkout page automatically

Comment: Its working bro

Comment: @vaibhav as per OP's comment , he need it in hyperlink

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is set session variable on checkout page(using observer or override controller) using below code

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$module = $request->getModuleName();
$controller = $request->getControllerName();
$action = $request->getActionName();
if($module == 'checkout' && $controller == 'onepage' && $action == 'index')
{
   Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setWasOnCheckout(true);
}
else
{
   if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getWasOnCheckout())
   {
     Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate();
     Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->save();
     Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setWasOnCheckout(false)
   }
}
```

you can use below link to learn how to use this code with observer  http://inchoo.net/magento/dispatching-before-and-after-events-to-magento-core-actions/

Comment: you can upvote if you like and mask as solution if it's work for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use Magento's event and observer functionality to accomplish what you want.

- Observe **`controller_action_layout_load_before`** event and call an observer function on this event.
- In the observer's function, check the last URL by using below code:

`$url = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');`

- Now match, if it is **`checkout onepage`** URL, then use below code to empty the cart:

  `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate();
  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->save();
  return;`

This method will help you even when you don't want to add a link to empty the cart.

Please let me know if it worked.